# The meaning of "sweet treats''

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In this video [The Truth About Sugar - New Documentary 2015](https://youtu.be/9E9bnjwQG9s?t=35s), a woman holds a donut in her hand and says 'I love my sweet treats'.

Does **sweet treats** mean sweet food in general?

Please give me some examples of this phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much so, but not quite. A "sweet treat" is a *serving* of sweet food: a donut, a piece of cake, a candy bar, a slice of pie, a handful of raisins, and so on. "Sweet food" is food that has sugar in it, so it's more general, for example cake, pie, candy, etc.

So, sweet treats are always sweet food, but sweet food isn't always sweet treats.

Comment: It might be helpful to expand on "treat". It means more than just "one serving of". If someone put a honey glaze on a pile of kale, it would be sweet, and I could take a single serving, but it wouldn't be a treat.

Comment: @ColleenV Feel free to do so. :) As for your example (Yuk LOL) something tells me that it would taste more like kale than honey to me.